# What is the term for the highest probability interval of a given length on the range of a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics

For example, for a standard normal distribution, if we are given an interval of length 10, then the most probable interval is [-5,5].

What is this type of interval called?

Comment: The way you've described it seems pretty good to me.  Why is it inadequate?

Comment: @John I am fine with "the most probable interval" but how do you indicate it is optimal among the class of intervals with "fixed lebesgue measure"? I was thinking "most probable fixed measure interval" but that seemed too wordy.

Comment: I am not aware of a specific name for it, but to avoid definition by example maybe "interval of given length containing maximal probability mass" is suitable? Wordy, but precise.

Comment: @Nameless it is precise, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't inventing a term in my article if one was out there in standard usage and I just don't happen to know it. I was thinking of calling it an "optimal fixed-measure-interval" with the hyphenation indicating that its an interval with constant measure (understood to be on the range of the random variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears that "most probable interval" is as short as it gets. Nothing standardized exists for this term.